# Audit on a vandalized question

Tags: discussion, review-audits

Going through review close queue, I hit this question which was smelling like an audit.
I took a look to the question itself and found it vandalized. I'm seem not able to roll it back.  [image]
Why can't roll it back and should this question stay as an audit question?

Link to the question:
[I'm working on a php shopping list function/api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059662/im-working-on-a-php-shopping-list-function-api)

Comment: I rolled it back for you, BTW.

Comment: Was it an audit?

Comment: thanks to michaelb958 (why couldn't I roll it back) and yes it was an audit.